# failed to import '@stripe/stripe-js' when using vue-stripe-js

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to implement a stripe payment system in my Laravel 9, Vue 3 site using vue-stripe-js from https://github.com/ectoflow/vue-stripe-js.

I ran `npm i vue-stripe-js --save-dev` and I see that my package.json file includes vue-stripe-js.

I'm using the code from the link above as is, reproduced here.

```
<template>
    <StripeElements
      v-if="stripeLoaded"
      v-slot="{ elements, instance }"
      ref="elms"
      :stripe-key="stripeKey"
      :instance-options="instanceOptions"
      :elements-options="elementsOptions"
    >
      <StripeElement
        ref="card"
        :elements="elements"
        :options="cardOptions"
      />
    </StripeElements>
    <button type="button" @click="pay">Pay</button>
  </template>

  <script lang="ts">
  import { StripeElements, StripeElement } from 'vue-stripe-js'
  import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'
  import { defineComponent, ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'CardOnly',

    components: {
      StripeElements,
      StripeElement,
    },

    setup() {
      const stripeKey = ref('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx') // test key
      const instanceOptions = ref({
        // https://stripe.com/docs/js/initializing#init_stripe_js-options
      })
      const elementsOptions = ref({
        // https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create#stripe_elements-options
      })
      const cardOptions = ref({
        // https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#element-options
        value: {
          postalCode: '12345',
        },
      })
      const stripeLoaded = ref(false)
      const card = ref()
      const elms = ref()

      onBeforeMount(() => {
        const stripePromise = loadStripe(stripeKey.value)
        stripePromise.then(() => {
          stripeLoaded.value = true
        })
      })

      const pay = () => {
        // Get stripe element
        const cardElement = card.value.stripeElement

        // Access instance methods, e.g. createToken()
        elms.value.instance.createToken(cardElement).then((result: object) => {
          // Handle result.error or result.token
          console.log(result)
        })
      }

      return {
        stripeKey,
        stripeLoaded,
        instanceOptions,
        elementsOptions,
        cardOptions,
        card,
        elms,
        pay
      }
    },
  })
  </script>
```

I'm getting an error `[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@stripe/stripe-js" from "resources/js/Pages/Billing/Subscribe.vue?vue&type=script&lang.ts".`

My package.json file doesn't include `@stripe/stripe-js`. If it should be there, how do I add it? I thought it would be added by the `npm i vue-stripe-js` command. If not, why else would I be getting this error?

Comment: `npm i @stripe/stripe-js`. Although this is common knowledge when working with `node`, you could open an issue on `vue-stripe-js`'s repo and suggest they update their readme to specify: `npm i vue-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js` (& the `yarn` equivalent).

Comment: Another good option for their package would be to specify `@stripe/stripe-js` as `peerDependency`. This automatically creates a console warning on systems which do not have `@stripe/stripe-js` installed, with clear instructions on how to add it.

Comment: Thanks. Clearly my node knowledge isn't yet common. Do you want to make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Go ahead, I'm not here for the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tao pointed out in his comment to the original question, `@stripe/stripe-js` should be added manually and will then appear in the package.json file.

```
npm i vue-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js
```